# How to drive a brushless motor using a commercial ESC with ROS?

Tags: python, ros

I am searching for a motor controller which can take ROS 
Geometry Twist Msg http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html as input and output the PWM signals that can be sent to the ESC and the servo motor.

System Info --- ROS : Melodic; OS : Ubuntu 18.04; RC Car : ZD Racing 10

To generate Twist msg, I am using Teleop http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy

To generate Odometry, I am using Laser http://wiki.ros.org/rf2o_laser_odometry

For the controller, I am using the Python Simple PID https://simple-pid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I have not been able to get any good result with this. There is too much overshoot. The system also has deadtime and large settling time.

I dont think I am first one trying this.. But I cant find much sample code on the internet.

It would be great if some sample project and codes can be shared.

Comment: Feed PWM signal to any pin you can control according the input and operator amplifier circuit amplifying the signal to correct level?

Comment: Thanks. But how do I generate the PWMs from the Twist msg.. Linear velocity can control the power of the dc motor... That relationship is easy to understand... But for angular velocity, how do I manage the 2 PWM signals? If the angular velocity changes, what do I change power or turn...??

Comment: Read either linear or angular vector value from the Twist message and use algroithm similar to this: http://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-pwm-generation-using-python-and-c

Comment: My servo which controls the steering takes value ranges from -50 (extreme left) to 50 (extreme right)
Similarly my bldc motor that drives the vehicle takes values range from -50 (extreme left) to 50 (extreme right)

So if I consider an angular velocity of -20... _How do i figure out if it is trying to go forward left or backward right...??_ In both cases the values can be -20 because physics says **angular velocity = linear velocity / turning radius**

Comment: Ah. I just noticed: "There is too much overshoot. The system also has deadtime and large settling time." You have to tune up the PID parameters to find correct ones. Will not be easy one, though. Maybe you should try to sample input signals faster in order to get better resolution on output, too? Could be also, that PID is not fast enough control algorithm in your case? Simple trapezoid function could be enough.